# progress spinner is not showing in action bar

Tags: android

I am trying to make app which will allow user to take photo and upload it to database, then it should show photos in listview. I want to show progress spinner in action bar when app is uploading photos. I tried to use code like this :

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);
}
...(doInBackground - uploading)
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.FALSE);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.photosList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}
```

But it's not showing anything. I'm newbie android developer, sorry if it's dumb question.

Comment: U can use progress dialog.

Comment: I know but user have to be able to use app while uploading

Comment: Okay..have you defined your spinner in xml ?

Comment: Just like I thought that's what I'm missing, can you tell me how to do this or give me some link, cause when I was looking for tutorials I just saw posts about this setSupport... things.

Comment: Tell me if it worked or not?

Comment: it's working, thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly Add Progress Bar in your Layout xml.**

```
  <ProgressBar
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/progressBar"
  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
  />
```

**Secondly Create circular_progress_bar.xml in your drawable folder.**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="90"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360">

<shape
  android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
  android:shape="ring"
  android:thicknessRatio="7.0">

  <gradient
     android:centerColor="#007DD6"
     android:endColor="#007DD6"
     android:startColor="#007DD6"
     android:angle="0"
     android:type="sweep"
     android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

    </rotate>
```

**And Finally Set it in your Activty**

```
private ProgressBar spinner;
spinner=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
  spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**And Set it wherever you want to show your progress spinner.**

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```