# Make ProgressBar Transparent after switching to AppCompat theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-styles, android-progressbar

After switching to the AppCompat theme my progressbars now have white backgrounds instead of transparent. I'm attempting to have a circular progressbar that overlays it's container with nothing but the spinning circle showing.  I have created a style for the progressbar as follows:

```
      <style name="ProgressBarStyle"        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

I have also assigned it in the theme using the following:

```
<item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBarStyle</item>
```

My progressbars still appear with a white background. I have also tried assigning the style programmatically but no success. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I guess You can use ProgressBar Spinner in it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34256464/5456493 check my this answer may be it is helpful.

Comment: did it worked for you?

Comment: No unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the solution. Thanks anyway